# Subscript and superscript symbols for chemical calculations

Tags: symbolic, subscript

I have some very unhandy, big equations which contain quantities like

$n_{AB}(^{13}C)$, now i would like to adapt this notation also in Mathematica so I do not need to think of a new one.
Is there a way?

Thanks

Zorg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, using either `Subscript[]` or the keyboard notation `ctrl+_`

or `ctrl+6` for `Superscript[]`

producing for example,

```
Subscript[d, x] x^2
```

or

```
Superscript[d,x] x^2
```

However this can end up causing effects that you weren't intending, such as:

The derivative of $\frac{\partial \left(x^2 d_x\right)}{\partial x}$ would be simply $2 x d_x$.

However without taking special care, and using D[] unintended answers can happen such as:

```
D[Subscript[d, x] x^2, x]
```

$$x^2 \text{Subscript}^{(0,1)}(d,x)+2 x d_x$$

Which certainly isn't what one intended. Because of this, it's generally better to just give your variables names such as $\left.n_{\text{ab}}(^{13}C\right)$ as `nAB13C` or something appropriate. Always starting with a lowercase letter as uppercase letters are reserved for commands such as `D[]` this will avoid any problems with future calculations dealing with variables and sub/superscripts

Have a look at this answer referring to [common pitfalls awaiting new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) for other tips.